# How to get Matrix from row-major vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, row-major-order, column-major-order

I have the following matrix:

```
50,60,55,67,70
62,65,70,70,81
72,66,77,80,69
```

I turn now the matrix into a vector but in row-major. This gives the following vector:

```
50,60,55,67,70,62,65,70,70,81,72,66,77,80,69
```

Now I would like to turn this vector into the same matrix as above. The problem is that `reshape(matrix,[3,5])` does not work because Matlab operates column-major.

How can this be done efficiently (for large matrices)?

Comment: Please check your examples again, from the vector using `reshape(matrix,[3,5])` Matlab produces exactly the matrix you have in your question.

Comment: @Daniel I have edited my example, sorry for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, use

```
reshape(matrix,[5,3]).'
```

First using reshape with row and column dimension swapped, you get a matrix with the right order but transposed, then using transpose you get the right output.

Having the control systems toolbox, you could also use [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html?refresh=true)

Comment: Thank you very much. How would it be done with vec2mat? Is reshape or vec2mat more efficient for large matrices?

Comment: I assume that there is no speed difference, but I can not test because I don't own the toolbox. The data has to be rearranged in memory, so for large matrices it may take some time.

Comment: @machinery If you look at `vec2mat`'s code you'll find that it has some overhead and then calls `reshape`. So `reshape` has to be faster

Comment: @LuisMendo: And I assume it can't do magic and requires transpose as well?

Comment: @Daniel :-) Yes, I forgot that